# How to add a Referer when using rvest to download pictures?

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape pictures from a website. Based on the great work of R package developers, I get the url for the picture. But I can not download the desired picture with download.file(). All I can get is a nonesense picture. I searched on stackoverflow and thought the problem is the anti-crawler mechanism of the website. Maybe I need to set the Referer for the scrape work. Is there anyone who can give a suggestion on how to fix this problem? It troubled me a lot, thanks in advance!

```
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(stringr)
myheader <- c(  "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; zh-CN; rv:1.9.1.6) ",  "Accept" = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",  "Accept-Language" = "en-us",  "Connection" = "keep-alive",  "Accept-Charset" = "GB2312,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",  "Referer" = "http://www.mm131.com")
url <- "http://www.mm131.com/mingxing/2016.html"

imgsrc <- html_session(url, add_headers(myheader))%>%   html_node(".content-pic img") %>%   html_attr('src')
download.file(imgsrc, "test.jpg",  mode = "wb")
```